# How does `getShift` and transform work on an SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I was just going though **[THIS](http://snapsvg.io/demos/#globe)** SVG animation demo , its pritty straightforward , i was jus tgoing through the JS code and came actoss the below lines of code;

```
var g = Snap();
g.attr({
    viewBox: [0, 0, 800, 600]
});

Snap.load("map.svg", function (f) {
    function getShift(dot) {
        return "t" + (400 - dot.x) + "," + (300 - dot.y);
    }
    var gr = f.select("g"),
        wrd = f.select("#world").attr({fill: "#fff"}),
        syd = f.select("#sydney").attr({fill: "red"}),
        msk = f.select("#san_francisco").attr({fill: "red"}),
        pth = f.select("#flight"),
        pln = f.select("#plane"),
        top = g.g()
    // DIFF above line of code , what is g.g();
    top.attr({
        mask: g.rect(100, 0, 600, 600).attr({
            fill: "r(.5,.5,.25)#fff-#000"
        })
    });
    top.add(gr);
    var click = top.text(410, 310, "click!").attr({
        font: "20px Source Sans Pro, sans-serif",
        fill: "#fff"
    });
    pth.attr({
        display: "none"
    });
    // DIFF , i am not quite understanding below line of code.
    pln = gr.g(pln, pln.clone());
    pln.attr({
        display: "none"
    });
    pln[0].attr({
        stroke: "#fff",
        strokeWidth: 2
    });
    gr.attr({
        transform: getShift({
            x: syd.attr("cx"),
            y: syd.attr("cy")
        })
    });
```

Now my question is about the below lines of code:

```
                  gr.attr({
                        transform: getShift({
                            x: syd.attr("cx"),
                            y: syd.attr("cy")
                        })
                    });
```

I beleive the layer `gr` is being transform , but i don't entirely understand this line of code , What exactly is `getShift` and ofcourse i do understand that the 'cx' and 'cy' attributes of the `syd` layer above are being used to transform the elements, but how does this line of code work as a whole and also what is `getShift` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getShift` itself has nothing to do specifically with the Snap library. It is defined in the top of the code you included, and simply returns a string based on an object you provide:

```
function getShift(dot) {
  return "t" + (400 - dot.x) + "," + (300 - dot.y);
}
```

So if you call `getShift` with a parameter of an object with the following properties, `{x: 10, y: 20}`, then `getShift` will return the string `"t380,290"`.

That string, however, can then be used by Snap to transform an element. Specifically, it is being used as follows:

```
gr.attr({transform: "t380,290"});
```

(based on my fictitious initial values).

It seems like what it's trying to do is the following: Translate the entire group (`"gr"`) (i.e. the whole world map?) such that the position of Sydney, Australia (`"syd"`) ends up at the coordinates (400, 300), i.e. in a pleasantly-viewable somewhat-central part of the screen/window/div. Without going through the entire code, it seems like this is probably setting up the characteristics for the end of the animation.

Comment: Well thanks alot andrew but i taught the value for  transform would never include a letter like `t` , i mean in css its usually `transform: translate(50%,50%)`, i am not quite understanding that syntax, or maybe its just because i am new to SVG .

Comment: The use of "t" for "translate" is from the Snap.svg library, not from the SVG spec itself. I find the Snap documentation frustratingly sparse, so I can't really point you to an "official" Snap explanation of its transform syntax. However, the Snap library was written by the same person who wrote the Raphael library and, while there are obviously differences between the two libraries, perhaps [this info](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html#Element.transform) from the Raphael documentation will help to explain "t" for "translate", "r" for "rotate", etc.